# Left join or inner join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, `Table_employee` has employee ID, salary, manager(the ID of each employee's respective manager), and another table
`Table_manager` which has each manager's first name, last name, and each manager's ID.

I was trying to create another table presenting manager's first name, last name, and count of employees each manager is responsible for and the total salary of those employees.

I am having trouble to have manager's first name and last name present.

My code is as below. Any helps would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

```
select 
   e.manager, 
   COUNT(e.employee_id), 
   SUM(e.salary) 
FROM 
   Table_employee e 
   Right outer join Table_manager m ON e.manager=m.employee_id 
GROUP BY 
   manager 
ORDER BY 
   manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add firstname and lastname to group by I think? Am I missing some complexity?

```
select e.manager, m.firstname, m.lastname, COUNT(e.employee_id), SUM(e.salary)
FROM Table_employee e
Right outer join Table_manager m ON e.manager=m.employee_id\
GROUP BY manager, m.firstname, m.lastname
ORDER BY manager
```

However, swapping order so that manager is on left and employee on right  makes more sense, so that you don't miss managers without employees:

```
select e.manager, m.firstname, m.lastname, COUNT(e.employee_id), SUM(e.salary)
FROM Table_manager m
Right outer join Table_employee e ON e.manager=m.employee_id
GROUP BY manager, m.firstname, m.lastname
ORDER BY manager
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and aggregation.  If you are learning SQL, just forget `RIGHT JOIN`.  It is almost never needed.  And `LEFT JOIN` is easier to follow ("keep everything in the *first* table" versus "keep everything in the *last* table, whatever that might be").

So:

```
select m.employee_id, m.firstname, m.lastname, 
       count(e.employee_id), sum(e.salary)
from Table_manager m left join
     Table_employee e
     ON e.manager = m.employee_id
group by m.employee_id, m.firstname, m.lastname
order by m.employee_id;
```